# Why doesn't Raphael.js show a gradient when using hover?

Tags: hover, raphael, gradient

I've created a button with Raphael.js that has a gradient background. Now I want to change to a different gradient when hovering over the button using `Element.hover`. But as soon as I move the mouse over the button, it starts showing only a solid color.

Here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruPGH/).

Maybe it's browser-related. I only tested Chrome and Safari under OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `transform` on the set afterwards. The `tranform()` method is deprecated, use the `transform` attr instead. Also, you might want to apply the transformation individually when you create the elements, as Raphael is known to have some issues in transforming sets uniformly.

Comment: You're right. It's the call to `transform` that triggers the problem. But when I set the `transform` attribute on each element individually, I get the same behavior. See my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruPGH/1/).

Comment: I think it's related to an issue in Raphael's handling of the transform matirx. If you call `attr()` after you set transformations it won't work - which is what your `hover` event does. [Here is the issue](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/476) and the fix, if manually modifying the Raphael source code is your cup of tea.

Comment: It seems that I hit exactly this issue. Thanks for your help.